# binding a listview to a collection.... Dynamic one

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

New to the WPF world and need to implement a dynamic column view.

I can conceptually visualize the idea, but am not able to turn this into an implementation.

StackPanel -> ListView -> Textboxes.

The whole idea is to display profiles as columns for a selected entity, based on the entity selected, the profiles can change, so I want to display profiles as dynamic columns.
A Profile will have 54 items, which can be represented as a textbox vertically.

So if i have an observable collection that represents the profile items (54 items), when bound to a usercontrol and user control loaded into the listview vertically.

So each profile added will be added horizontally on the stack panel, so i can get all profiles as dynamic columns.

Any ideas or pointers on how i can implement this via xaml, and how should my model objects should look like ?

Hope i have put my idea across properly :)

** adding a very quick hand sketch of whats required.

The columns col1..col2..... are ideally a collection that has the data to be displayed in the textboxes denoted by the rectangle boxes inside the column.

Each colum across can be varied.

so the data I get from my service ideally is a Collection of Collection.

so The first collection contains the Col1..Col2..Col3... items...

At first thought this sounds very much like a grid, but the datamodel does not fit a grid display style.

Each of those Col1..col2..col3 is inside the first collection as another collection.[image]

Comment: Its a little confusing here, please explain more or give at least an example, that would be great !

Comment: This is a bit difficult to visualize from your description, maybe a quick mock-up wireframe or something to help visually convey what you're asking for would help? Otherwise just going from what's perceived I would say you want an ItemsControl or a DataGrid. Though I would hesitate to provide an example without a better visualization of what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, will mock up a screen and add it for a better understanding, will do it asap

Comment: added image and more description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the layout and display of the data as required above, thanks to SO and a mix and match of various answers got me this.

So the below XAML creates any number of listitems horizontally.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Height="301"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,42,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="795">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="Silver" Offset="0.006" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Height="209" Name="listBox1" Width="98" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Profile, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```